# Why creation of login form in react with axios doesn't work?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, axios

Hello I am trying to create login form to connect to mongodb. Everything is correctly install but I keep getting the error
`AxiosError code: "ERR_BAD_REQUEST"`

```
import { useState } from "react"
import axios from 'axios'




export default function Login(){

const [email ,setEmail] = useState('')
   const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
   const handleSubmit = (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault()
    axios.post('http://localhost:5173/login' ,{email ,password})
    .then(result => console.log(result))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }
    console.log(email)
    console.log(password)

    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <div>
                    <label htmlFor="email">email</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email"  onChange={(e)=> setEmail(e.target.value)}/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label htmlFor="email">password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password"  onChange={(e)=> setPassword(e.target.value)}/>
                </div>
                <button type="submit">log in </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I ahve already checked the port and endpoind, and they are correct and that is link to code server `https://www.useblackbox.io/editor?id=7849c828-bd17-4885-b17f-07a3f6d3bad1`

Comment: What's the status code you are getting? Inspect the network tab to find it.

Comment: AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 404', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
this one

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain this endpoint is correct? [Status code 404 means not found](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/404)

```
http://localhost:5173/login
```

Comment: yes i use the link get to the page of the login and work

Comment: Update your answer with the full error. Your app is most likely running on a different port.

Answer (score 0):

AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 404', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
code: "ERR_BAD_REQUEST"
config: {transitional: {…}, adapter: Array(2), transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, …}
message: "Request failed with status code 404"
name: "AxiosError"
request: XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}
response: {data: '', status: 404, statusText: 'Not Found', headers: AxiosHeaders, config: {…}, …}
stack: "AxiosError: Request failed with status code 404\n    at settle (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/axios.js?v=55c2aff0:1206:12)\n    at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/axios.js?v=55c2aff0:1423:7)"
[[Prototype]]: